# Error "Your account has not been authorized to select the Lite Plan" when creating a free IBM Cloud Analytics Engine instance using Lite account

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

I following one of the hadoop courses from cognitievclass.ai and was attempting to create an Analytics Engine instance as instructed. As mentioned in the IBM Cloud catalog, the Analytics Engine is available for Lite accounts for free but whenever I do the configurations and try to create the instance using my Lite account, it gives me the following error.

> Your account has not been authorized to select the Lite plan. Upgrade your account to a paid IBM Cloud account to create an instance of a paid plan of the service

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEeVq.png)

Why is this error popping up? My account was created less than 30 days ago and in my account settings it says my account is a Lite account. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

oh, i guess that occur when your account have no development activity after 30 days, your instance with Lite plan wil be deleted 
Here are link you may want to know more detail : 
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#liteaccount